# RN-42 Drops connection on SPP profile

Tags: windows, networking, bluetooth, embedded

I am using RN42 on embedded device connected to UART. Baudrate is 115200 ( I tried lowering it but didnt help. )

I am using default settings.

Every time when I pair a device with PC I can open a serial port to remote device, but as soon as i Close the port, and I try to open it again It will fail with "semaphore timeout error".

If I want to restore connection I have to delete device from PC and add it again, then it will work for 1st time and fail again.

Does anyone have similar issues or maybe solution to this? If you need more info ask, I realy dont know what info to supply in this case.

On PC side I have USB Bluetooth device and integrated one. The both behave the same. 
On embedded side RN42 is connected to UART of AM3517.

I hope you can help me.

Regards,
Luka

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having a very similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was PIN3 (GPIO6) connected high. This way after 1 connection module switched to auto master and was unable to connect to other masters.